Why is this excel macro failing to run non-interactively via task scheduler since a windows update
I have a bat file, that executes a vbscript, that runs an excel macro (I'm using Excel 2016). This is running on a Windows Server. Everything worked ok for years until the server was upgraded from Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2022.
Since then, the script works perfectly when I run it myself, but crashes at a certain point when I run via task scheduler with the 'run whether the user is logged in or not option'
The macro is:
Sub MegaMacro()
    metaData = Range("metaData")

    'load metadata
    Drive = "D:\Build\SAP\Broadcasts\"
    
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Drive & metaData, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
    Workbooks(metaData).Close
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="D:\Build\SAP\Broadcasts\test.xls"
    
End Sub

The point in the macro that the script crashes is when it tries to open another file. If I exclude this row line and the line below that closes the file, it works fine. I've tried to open several files this way and the behaviour is the same, so I don't think the file itself is to blame.
I have created the following folders as I know they're required for this:
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
I'm thinking it must be a difference in the environments between running a application interactively and non-interactively, but I'm unable to determine what the difference is.

Why not add some logging to your VBA so you can get a little more information about what might be going wrong?  Difficult to offer any more than that without any code.

My guess would be a "security enhancement" ie user/file permissions .

@TimWilliams good point, I've added the code. Obviously the full macro does more than this but this is a cut down version I've been testing.
I'm not entirely sure what logging I can add as it just crashes on the Workbooks.Open line, but anything you can suggest would be appreicated

I found this old thread which mentioned some other folders that needed creating. After checking with ProcMon to confirm that my machine was also looking for these folders, I created:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Documents
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
Now my script is working as expected when run non-interactively

Logging example:
Sub MegaMacro()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, metaData, Drive
    
    On Error GoTo haveError
    
    metaData = Range("metaData") 'better to specify a worksheet here...

    'load metadata
    Drive = "D:\Build\SAP\Broadcasts\"
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Drive & metaData, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    '...
    '...
    wb.Close False
    
    'ThisWorkbook?
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="D:\Build\SAP\Broadcasts\test.xls"
    
    LogMsg "Success"
    Exit Sub
    
haveError:
    LogMsg "##Error##:" & Err.Description
    
End Sub

'Write timestamp and `msg` to file at LOG_FILE
Sub LogMsg(msg As String)
    Const LOG_FILE As String = "C:\Temp\VBALog.txt" 'make sure writeable by "everyone" for testing...
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").OpenTextFile(LOG_FILE, 8, True) '8=append
        .WriteLine Format(Now, "yyyymmdd hh:nn") & " - " & msg
        .Close
    End With
End Sub

It's good to have a log even when there are no issues...

Thanks so much! Unfortunately the log doesn't appear because excel just outright crashes at the 'Set wb =...' line when run via task scheduler

If even error handling doesn't work then I'm not sure what the solution would be.  Can you get log file content with just  LogMsg "Starting" at the top of the script?  Might be useful to also include your vbscript here.
